# How to get Avg value same when group by also?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have 3 columns like FreqHeader, Frequency and Avgwaittime in a table. When I get avg of Avgwaittime it is 26.66. If i get avg of Avgwaittime group by FreqHeader, Frequency it's giving 25.15.

How can I get 26.66 even I grouping the FreqHeader, Frequency?

This is my table:

```
FreqHeader  Frequency   Avgwaittime
Week         19         6.73
Week         19         96.62
Week         20         15.22
Week         20         20.84
Week         20         41.77
Week         21         9.01
Week         21         25.42
Week         21         31.20
Week         22         36.01
Week         22         17.20
Week         22         17.05
Week         23         2.85
```

The avg of above Avgwaittime is 26.66

This is my query

```
SELECT FreqHeader, Frequency, CAST(AVG(Avgwaittime) as decimal(10,2)) Avgwaittime
from #temp
GROUP BY FreqHeader, Frequency

FreqHeader  Frequency   Avgwaittime
Week          19        51.68
Week          20        25.94
Week          21        21.88
Week          22        23.42
Week          23        2.85
```

when i calculate avg of this 5 records is should be 26.66.But here is is 25.15

Comment: MySQL or MS SQL Server? (Remove one of the product tags.)

Comment: With that table data, what's the expected result?

Comment: Do you want to add a column, showing the `AVG(AvgWaitTime)`?

Comment: The first thing to note is that average of an average is not a good statistical measure.

Comment: I just can't think why you'd want this - and why are you storing averages as strings !?!?!?

Comment: This isn't an issue with SQL Server, it is a mathematics problem. The sum of all the data points is 319.92 and divided by the number of data points (12) provides 26.66. The sum of the grouped averages is 125.77 and divided by the data points (5) gives 25.15. To understand the concepts involved you'd be better posting on the [Mathematics Exchage](http://math.stackexchange.com/)

Answer (score 0):

You have to use a subquery:

```
SELECT FreqHeader, Frequency, 
       CAST(AVG(Avgwaittime) as decimal(10,2)) Avgwaittime,
       (SELECT CAST(AVG(Avgwaittime) as decimal(10,2))  FROM mytable) AS AvgwaittimeOverall
from mytable
GROUP BY FreqHeader, Frequency
```

Comment: @betsos in your query you adding another column  AvgwaittimeOverall.i want avg Avgwaittime should be 26.66. jest now i updated my query please see my question.

Comment: @surendra I'm afraid I don't understand your actual requirement. Can you add the expected result?

Comment: @betsos when i calculate avg of Avgwaittime from my result it should be 26.66. That is AVG(51.68,25.94,21.88,23.42,2.85) should be 26.55 not 25.15

Comment: @surendra But this is not mathematically possible.

Comment: @betsos why its not possible ? please elaborate the problem behind that is help me a lot.

Comment: @surendra Just do the math and you will see for yourself.

Answer (score 0):

Below query will the required output :-

```
SELECT FreqHeader, Frequency, 
(select CAST(AVG(COALESCE(Avgwaittime,0)) as decimal(10,2)) from table_name) Avgwaittime
from table_name
GROUP BY FreqHeader, Frequency
```

Output :-

```
  FreqHeader    Frequency   Avgwaittime
    Week           19         26.66
    Week           20         26.66
    Week           21         26.66
    Week           22         26.66
    Week           23         26.66
```